# does receivedApplicationContext need to be stored?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos, watchconnectivity

I was wondering if `receivedApplicationContext` needs to be stored after it is received or if it is readily available until the next context update? For instance, after I close my watch app and I relaunch, is the last context still going to be accessible in `receivedApplicationContext`? The apple docs don't really clarify this. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968149/watchkit-app-losing-data-after-going-background-swift) is using UserDefaults and I'm not sure if its necessary. After playing around with xcode it seems like `receivedApplicationContext` does become empty at some point, but I'm not sure if thats just behavior associated with the simulator.